# Adding an html wrapper to a custom Block Pattern

Tags: block-editor

I've registered a custom block pattern using `register_block_pattern` with several block elements, and I'd like to wrap the whole thing in a container element. When I add it to the content, however, it doesn't render correctly. Rather than wrapping the other block elements, as coded, it self-closes, and a grey "Classic" box shows in the editor. Is there a way to add extra html that isn't a registered block to a custom block pattern?

Example of the (unescaped) code and desired output (the .wrapper class is the added code):

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- wp:heading -->
    <h1 class="has-text-align-center">Block 1</h1>
    <!-- /wp:heading -->

    <!-- wp:heading -->
    <h5 class="has-text-align-center">Block 2</h5>
    <!-- /wp:heading -->
</div>
```

Actual Result after adding the block pattern to a page:

```
<div class="wrapper"></div>

<!-- wp:heading -->
<h1 class="has-text-align-center">Block 1</h1>
<!-- /wp:heading -->

<!-- wp:heading -->
<h5 class="has-text-align-center">Block 2</h5>
<!-- /wp:heading -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *group* block comes to mind as an out of the box pattern wrapper with a custom class `mywrapper`:

```
<!-- wp:group {"className":"mywrapper"} -->
<div class="wp-block-group mywrapper"><div class="wp-block-group__inner-container">

...pattern...

</div></div>
<!-- /wp:group -->
```

Theoretically one can use the custom html block as a pattern, like:

```
<!-- wp:html -->
<div class="mywrappper">
   <h1 class="has-text-align-center">Block 1</h1>
   <h2 class="has-text-align-center">Block 2</h2>
</div>
<!-- /wp:html -->
```

but not the best user experience :-)

If you want to write your own block to handle this, the [InnerBlocks](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/nested-blocks-inner-blocks/)  component supports nested blocks and in [version 2](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/18/block-api-version-2/) of the block api it becomes e.g.:

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { InnerBlocks, useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

registerBlockType( 'wpse/wrapper', {
    apiVersion: 2,
    title: __( 'WPSE Wrapper', 'wpse' ),
    icon: 'text-page', 
    category: 'design', 
    edit: ( props ) => {
        const blockProps = useBlockProps( { className: 'mywrapper' } );
        return <div { ...blockProps }><InnerBlocks /></div>;
    },
    save: ( props ) => {
        const blockProps = useBlockProps.save( { className: 'mywrapper' } );
        return <div { ...blockProps }><InnerBlocks.Content /></div>;
    },
} );
```

Then you can wrap the block pattern  with:

```
<!-- wp:wpse/wrapper -->
<div class="wp-block-wpse-wrapper mywrapper">

...pattern...

</div>
<!-- /wp:wpse/wrapper -->
```

to generate a div wrapper containing the  `.mywrapper` class.

Comment: Yes, perfect! The block group is exactly what I needed, but wasn't documented in the list of core blocks. I should have looked at the code of one of the core block patterns, as it was used just like this.

Comment: yes, hopefully the docs will catch on